# Update field on field change trigger

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a trigger that sets an updated flag when a field is changed. The reason I can't do it with a basic `UPDATE` query is because the change will come from a `INSERT ON DUPLICATE UPDATE`.

This is the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_update_flag BEFORE UPDATE ON `reputation_email_score`
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.`score` <> OLD.`score` THEN
          SET NEW.`updated` = "yes";
        END IF;
    END;
```

When I try to run it, I get these errors:

```
Error in query (1064): Syntax error near '' at line 5
Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'END IF' at line 1
Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'END' at line 1
```

What is wrong in my SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget about DELIMITER:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER set_update_flag BEFORE UPDATE ON `reputation_email_score`
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.`score` <> OLD.`score` THEN
          SET NEW.`updated` = "yes";
        END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

also ; after last END - not necessary

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell this was my first attempt at a trigger? haha

Comment: in 90% of cases - I create procedures or triggers thru IDE, such as DBVisualizer or Navicat, and it not necessary, so it normal